# selenium declared package doesn't match expected package

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am leaning selenium. I have trouble to run a sample script. Please help me to figure out what I did wrong. Thanks!
My installations: 
JDK1.7.0._02
selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
Eclipse IDE 3.7.0
Selenium IDE 1.9.0 (Firefox plugin)

Eclipse indicates the following error message when I click on the package section in the code
1.the declared the package org.openqa.selenium.example; doesn't match expected package Seletest1
2. syntax error on token package, imported expected
Eclipse also suggested move Test1.java to package 'org.openqa.selenium.example

Please suggest the right action for me to take, should I imported org.openqa.selenium.example into the build path of my project or should I move Test1.java into the package?

where Can I find out the location of the package-org.openqa.selenium.example?

Here is my code copied from Google code get started with Selenium
my project structure SeleniumTest1>Src>SeleTet1

```
package SeleTest1;
package org.openqa.selenium.example;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Test1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }

}
```

The error message showed when I execute the code
When I run the code in Eclipse, I received the following error message: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
   The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export the selenmium IDE recorded test case into webdriver format, by default the package statement will get added as

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;
```

We need to modify it as per our package name created in Eclipse.

So, in your case, you can remove the below duplicate line.

```
package org.openqa.selenium.example;
```

You will not get the 2nd error also once you have done this modification.

Comment: Hello hemChe, after removing the package line suggested by you. I received the following errors.

Comment: I have 2 projects located in the same workspace. after removing the package line suggested by you. I received the following errors. 1.The declared package "" does not match the expected package "helloworld" <br />Resource: MyFirstClass.java Path: /helloworld/src/helloworld <br/>The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String) Resource:MyFirstTest.java Path:/SeleTest1/src/Test1. Should I create a new workspace, or I need to remove some file to separate 2 projects, so they don't affect each other the complication time?

Comment: It seems you have created a package named "helloworld"
add the line `package helloworld;` to your program. There is no need to create another workspace. If you have two java files in the same project under the package 'helloworld' then both the java files should have the first statement as `package helloworld;`

Comment: I solved the issue by adding package helloworld; to  MyFirstClass.java file, it removed error 1. for error 2, I googled the web and used element.sendKeys(new String[] {"Cheese!"}); but I am still not sure why it worked. Does it have to do with my selenium version 3.7.0 or the JDK version?

Answer (score 2):

You have a duplicate package declaration on the top of your code. I would remove the second one (`org.openqa.selenium.example`) since your code is probably in the `SeleTest1` folder.

Your package declaration is not required to match the one of the framework you are using.

Comment: I have 2 projects located in the same workspace.  after removing the package line suggested by you. I 
received the following errors. 1.The declared package "" does not match the expected package "helloworld"  <br />Resource: 
MyFirstClass.java Path: /helloworld/src/helloworld  <br/>The method sendKeys(CharSequence[]) in the type WebElement is not applicable for the arguments (String) Resource:MyFirstTest.java Path:/SeleTest1/src/Test1. Should I create a new workspace, or I need to remove some file to separate 2 projects, so they don't affect each other the complication time?

Comment: @user2061466 The package of the class must correspond to the folder name the java source file is in. If your .java file is inside the folder `helloworld`, you can either rename your package to `helloworld`, or rename the folder to whatever package you have declared. For package names like `com.example`, you will need nested folders: `.../com/example`.

Comment: thank for the reply. I solved the issue by adding package helloworld; to  MyFirstClass.java file, it removed error 1. for error 2, I googled the web and used element.sendKeys(new String[] {"Cheese!"}); but I am still not sure why it worked. Does it have to do with my selenium version 3.7.0 or the JDK version?

Comment: From Google search, I found the cause of the issue. In Eclipse, the project's compiler is set to 1.2. The build process complained that the parameter types need version 1.5 or higher. I changed the compiler to 1.7>clean the build path>rebuild the project. The errors are gone. These 2 posts helped me: http://bit.ly/J4zhaj , http://bit.ly/10jADrB. Thanks again for your help!